# Understanding this sentence: 心配で心配で

Tags: translation, words, syntax

I was playing Fire Emblem yesterday and this came up:[image: Fire emblem dialogue]

Some context: Odin is Leon's retainer, but they have been sent on separate missions, hence the worry of the retainer towards its lord.

I simply don't understand the answer by Odin, especially why he uses `心配で心配で`. I am also unsure as to which words he is using in second line : 煩慮{はんりょ} and 慮無｛りょむ｝? They are not present in the JMDict based dictionaries, and my input method does not propose them, are they common ?

I understand the global sense as expressing a lot of worry: it will take Odin a long time to get rid of his worry. I would like help to understand it more precisely.

Additional question: what kind of "style" is Odin using here ?

Full transcription:

> レオン：後｛あと｝は好｛す｝きにしていいってさ。
>   だからこれからは、僕｛ぼく｝も一緒｛いっしょ｝に闘｛たたか｝うよ。
>
> オーディン：俺{おれ}もうお傍｛そば｝を離｛はな｝れている間｛あいだ｝心配で心配で
>   煩慮の念｛ねん｝が永{なが}き慮無｛りょむ｝に廃{はい}されるのではと…！

Comment: That is like very very, more and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeating 心配{しんぱい} twice (心配で心配で) is just a way to emphasize that he is *really* worried. I guess you could say this in English, "While he is away, I am just so terribly worried." 「[離]{はな}れている[間]{あいだ}心配で心配で」

It is often used in conjunction with 「たまらない」 eg,
It is formed like this:
Adjective [(「て」, 「で」 form)](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-adjectives-2.html) followed by 「たまらない」

> 心配で心配でたまらない
>   unbearably worried

Other examples would be,

> 痛{いた}くて痛くてたまらない
>   unbearably painful

In a positive sense,

> 嬉{うれ}しくて嬉しくてたまらない
>   tremendously happy

Regarding the Kanji you mentioned, you have made a mistake, it is not 慮無{りょむ} but 虚無｛きょむ｝. Nevertheless, 煩慮{はんりょ} as well as 虚無 are hardly ever used in everyday life.

Here are two links to their definition [煩慮](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%85%A9%E6%85%AE) and [虚無](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%99%9A%E7%84%A1%E7%9A%84).

Answer (score 0):

As another person said, 虚無 is correct, but even for me (a native Japanese speaker), second line is still difficult.
If you understand atmosphere of that, you don't have to care details.

However, maybe second line means like this:
I'm so worried. Because of worry, I won't be able to do anything for a long time.
（煩慮＝worry or buzz feeling 虚無＝nothing）